# Turn off Mail Notification from TFS 2015 when renaming a project

Tags: email, tfs, notifications, tfs-2015

As the title explains, i want to turn off the automatic Email that is sent per Project Collection, when a project is renamed.

thx,
regards

Comment: Found featurerequest, pls [upvote](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13019715-possible-to-turn-off-notification-email-when-renam)